# Start date Summertime/Wintertime

Tags: javascript, datetime

In google apps script I use often in summertimeperiod GMT+2 or in wintertime GMT+1 for the correct date.
To avoid to change this twice a year manually i developped following function:

```
function StartSummerWintertime() {
  var i;
  var today;
  var year;
  var SST;
  var SWT;
  var day;
  var GMT_time;
  today = new Date();
  Logger.log("today = " + today)
  year = today.getFullYear();
  //Summertime starts last Sunday in March.
  for (i = 31; i > 24; i--) {
    SST = new Date("March " + i + "," + year);
    day = SST.getDay();
    if (day == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Start date Summertime "+year+" = " + SST)
  //Wintertime starts last Sunday in October.
  for (i = 31; i > 24; i--) {
    SWT = new Date("Oct " + i + "," + year);
    day = SWT.getDay();
    if (day == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Start date Wintertime "+year+" = " + SWT)
  //The switch takes place at 2:00 AM, so I have added 2 hours (= 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ms)
  if (today.getTime() < (SST.getTime() + 2*60*60*1000) || today.getTime() > SWT.getTime() + (2*60*60*1000)) {
    GMT_time = "GMT+1";
  }
  else {
    GMT_time = "GMT+2";
  }
  Logger.log("GMT_time = " + GMT_time)
var date1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date("July 6, 2021"), "GMT+2", "d-M-yyyy");
var date2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date("July 6, 2021"), "GMT+1", "d-M-yyyy");
Logger.log("date1 = " + date1)
Logger.log("date2 = " + date2)
var date3 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date("July 6, 2021"), GMT_time, "d-M-yyyy");
var date4 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date("July 6, 2021"), GMT_time, "d-M-yyyy");
Logger.log("date3 = " + date3)
Logger.log("date4 = " + date4)
}
```

Date 1 and date 2 give different dates, date 3 and date 4 give correct (same) dates. The problem is solved however there should be a smarter (shorter) way to do so.
Please advise.

Comment: why dont you use the built in javascript timezone support or use a library?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: This is a good advise! Thanks Daniel.